# Considering a permutation representation of a transitive $G$-set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $X$ is a transitive $G$-set, where the size is greater than $1$, and $\pi=\pi_X$ the associated permutation representation. What is its character $\chi$?

I thought that the permutation representation is the number of fixed points in each conjugacy class. Here I have two problems I cannot see what the conjugacy classes could be nor can I see how many fixed points there should be.

Hints please no full solutions.

Comment: Here are some hints. First, conjugacy classes in $G$ are subsets of $G$ and completely independent of $X.$ Second, for $g\in G$ we have $\chi(g) = $ "number of fixed points of $g$ on $X$". Third, if $g,h\in G$ are conjugate, then $\chi(g) = \chi(h).$ I think, you already know all of this. If you're searching for examples for the possible number of fixed points of individual group elements, look at the natural action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}.$

Comment: @jflipp: You should post that as an answer.